# the use of live as a verb

Tags: verbs

I came across this sentence:

> Mangroves live life on the edge.

Looking it up in a dictionary, I learned that "live" is transitive when it means " to spend your life in a particular way. " If it is the case, then why the determiner "a" or "the" is not used here since life can be countable when it means the activities and experiences that are typical of a particular way of living ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a determiner in this example:

> Mangroves live life on the edge.

You could use the possessive determiner *their* and say they "live *their* life on the edge", but there is no doubt that one can only live their own life, so although it would be grammatically correct, it would be no more idiomatic and somewhat redundant.

Consider as an example:

> Charlie eats dinner at the table.

You could say Charlie eats *his* dinner - but there would be no need unless perhaps you were trying to draw a comparison between someone else who did not eat their dinner at the table.

---

In both your example and mine, the nouns are uncountable. They refer to *all* the lives of *all mangroves*, and *all* the dinners you eat. There is no need for an article unless you were referring to a *specific* dinner or a *specific* life, for example:

> Mangroves live a life of luxury.

This has an article to show because we are talking about a particular kind of life.

Although your example of "a life on the edge" is arguably a kind, or way of life, it is an idiomatic way of saying "dangerously". Saying "they live a dangerous life" does not mean the same - "a dangerous life" would be a life filled with danger, but to live dangerously means that you take deliberate risks.

You don't give context for your quotation, but it is possible that your particular example is not a literal use of this idiom anyway. Mangroves are a coastal plant, and plants don't really literally live dangerously. I think it is a pun, because a coastline (where mangroves grow) is the "edge" of the land.

Comment: I figure "on the edge" may have specified what kind of a life it is, so an article is needed here for this specific life.

Comment: @CharlieWang I've added some detail to the end of my answer, I think there may be some other things you need to understand.